# Why Xcode Cloud fails to recognize the fulfillment(of:timeout:enforceOrder:) method

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode-cloud

Xcode Cloud fails to run some of my tests. Looks like it does not recognize the [`fulfillment(of:timeout:enforceOrder:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xctestcase/4109476-fulfillment) method.

[image: Xcode error]

The error I am getting is:

```
Cannot find 'fulfillment' in scope
```

The triggering code is very simple and when run locally, all is green. I changed the names of the variables but it looks like this:

```swift
func testThatFooThrows() async throws  {
  // GIVEN
  let expectation = expectation(description: "Expect to throw error")

  let fooMock = FooMock<Bar>()
  fooMock.failWithBadUrlError()

  let sut = FooService(contentID: "Test", myService: fooMock)

  // WHEN
  do {
      _ = try await sut.doSomething()
  } catch {
      expectation.fulfill()
  }

  // THEN
  await fulfillment(of: [expectation], timeout: 0.1)
}
```

Everything seems to work when I change the failing line to:

```swift
wait(for: [expectation], timeout: 0.1)
```

[image]

```
Instance method 'wait' is unavailable from asynchronous contexts; 
Use await fulfillment(of:timeout:enforceOrder:) instead; 
this is an error in Swift 6
```

However, as the warning says, this is not the best.

The documentation says that the [`fulfillment(of:timeout:enforceOrder:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xctestcase/4109476-fulfillment) method is available starting with Xcode 11. My Xcode Cloud setup uses `Xcode 14.3.1 (14E300c)` and `macos Ventura 13.5 (22G74)`

How can I make Xcode Cloud "see" the `fulfillment(of:timeout:enforceOrder:)` method?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I'm having the same problem with our CI/CD server. It uses Xcode 14.2 that should support `await fulfilment(_)` but it shows the same error.

Comment: Sadly, no solution so far :(

Comment: I figured out `fufillment(_)` is only available with Swift 5.8+. Xcode 14.2 uses Swift 5.7. So this worked:
`#if swift(>=5.8)
        await fulfillment(of: [expectation])
#else
        wait(for: [expectation])
#endif`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be an issue with the version of Swift. `await fulfillment(_)` is available only from Swift 5.8. So you could try something like this:

```
#if swift(>=5.8)
    await fulfillment(of: [expectation])
#else
    wait(for: [expectation])
#endif
```